How to BLOCK a Website with an Access Rule in SONICWALL Router
I'm trying to block a website using an access rule on my SonicWall router, but it isn't working. Here is my configuration:
Created an address object:
Zone Assignment: WAN
Type: FQDN
Entered the domain with a *. before the domain name
Created an access rule:
From: LAN
To: WAN
Action: Deny
Destination Address: Set to the address object created
All other settings left to 'Any'
I've tried this configuration with multiple domains and even the IP addresses of the websites, but the rule is still not working. Can someone explain why this rule might not be functioning as expected?
